# Passing a small structure by value to a non-inline function is slow with visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, clang

CppCoreGuideline [suggests](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#f16-for-in-parameters-pass-cheaply-copied-types-by-value-and-others-by-reference-to-const) that two or three words (doubles, pointers, references) are usually best passed by value. But visual studio's compiler is significantly slower when we pass a small structure by value to a non-inline function than passing it by const ref.

Here is the prototype of structure and functions used:

```
using TypeToTest = size_t;
struct MyStruct
{
    TypeToTest a;
    TypeToTest b;
};

__declspec(noinline) auto MyFunc(MyStruct st)
{
       auto sum = st.a + st.b;
       return sum;
}

__declspec(noinline) auto MyFunc1(const MyStruct& st)
{
       auto sum = st.a + st.b; 
       return sum;
}
```

See: [live demo with visual studio](http://rextester.com/DUX94458)

```
passing struct By Val    : 1131 µs // almost 3x slower
passing struct By Const& : 351 µs
```

See: [live demo with clang](http://rextester.com/MEOYC85397)

```
passing struct By Val    : 184 µs
passing struct By Const& : 190 µs
```

See: [live demo with gcc](http://rextester.com/WUJZB76957)

```
passing struct By Val    : 179 µs
passing struct By Const& : 180 µs
```

Note: I forced noinline for the functions used so that some numbers actually show up.

So, given the VC++ behavior, while writing portable code across different compilers, should we rather pass such structures by const reference than by value?

Comment: Basic types are best passed by value. Whenever you encounter a more complex struct/class you should pass it by ref/pointer (or const ref/pointer). Just out of curiosity, did you do the test on your machine or the internet ?

Comment: Also, I would suggest you change your code so you do not always recreate the object. Each time interval you posted includes the time to create the struct. (There might be compiler optimizations being done also because you create the object & directly use it to call the functions).

Comment: A small pod structure should also be cheap to pass by value in my opinion. Results were similar with VC++ on my machine as well. Sure, I'll also try your suggestion.

Comment: your measurement is quite interesting, but its not quite clear what is the question

Comment: @AlexG, it produced similar result even with avoiding object creation inside the loop, demo: http://rextester.com/YXQ18915

Comment: this is really weird, [here](https://godbolt.org/g/AF6fA4) you can see it produces **exactly** the same code (which is kinda expected), are you sure  there is no compiler flags that could've interfere?

Comment: @tobi303, I've updated the question details to be more specific.

Comment: assuming your observations are correct, imho it is VC++ that has to do something to the compiler not we have to change our code to adopt to that situation. tbh I am not quite convinced by your numbers, profiling small code snippets can give a hint, but to see the impact on a real project one has to profile the real project

Comment: [My results differ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQDRS.png).  They fluctuate but they average out to be about the same.

Comment: @Ap31, that's not about functions' code, it's obvious that they will be almost the same. It's about the places that call these functions.

Comment: @NathanOliver, That's interesting; I'll give it a try on some different machine.

Comment: I just compiled in release mode.  I know it uses O2 optimization but I do not know all the other flags.

Comment: @iehrlich agreed, the caller does seem to create an actual copy for `MyFunc`... There better be some good reason for that

Comment: @Ap31 it's just a straightforward non-optimized behavior. I assume MSVC++ has a flag to optimize such places. The best course of action here is to take a look at the compiler diagnostics from the actual compilation.

Comment: @NathanOliver, I tried it again on a different machine with VS2017, but they were more or less similar to my earlier results.

Answer (score 0):

I ran a test with g++ 4.8.4 under Ubuntu 14.04 x86_64 with the same options as on rextester (-Wall -O2 -std=c++11). The results are the same as yours. The assembly generated for the functions is as follows:

```
0000000000400be0 <_Z6MyFunc8MyStruct>:
  400be0:       48 8d 04 3e             lea    (%rsi,%rdi,1),%rax
  400be4:       c3                      retq   
  400be5:       66 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00    data32 nopw %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  400bec:       00 00 00 00 

0000000000400bf0 <_Z7MyFunc1RK8MyStruct>:
  400bf0:       48 8b 47 08             mov    0x8(%rdi),%rax
  400bf4:       48 03 07                add    (%rdi),%rax
  400bf7:       c3                      retq   
  400bf8:       0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  400bff:       00
```

There's an important detail here: gcc *does not* create an object copy in either function. In the first one (which is `MyFunc`) the contents of the struct are just loaded to CARG1 and CARG2 registers (`$rdi` and `$rsi` respectively) and then there's an on-register add via `lea` followed by `retq`. In the second one (which is `MyFunc1`), pointer to the structure is passed in `$rdi`, and then again, two loads, add, return. These two functions are almost equal in terms of the actual performance, the only difference is where struct fields are loaded to the registers - in the caller (for `MyFunc`), or in the function itself (for `MyFunc1`).

Based on what I've seen, I assume that MSVC++ just bothers itself with **actually** creating a copy of your input structure - hence the performance difference.

As a sidenote, I assume that gcc might behave closer to MSVC++ on x86.